# Custom ServiceStack OAuth2 provider

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, servicestack

We are trying to communicate with a REST server, which uses its own OAuth2 implementation.
This server is written by another company in Java, so I don't have much influence about it.
I've got all the necessary information, like Access Token URL, Refresh URL, Client Id, Client Secret, etc. I can already request an access token and then request some other data from this server, using the REST client Postman.

Now I'd like to use the ServiceStack client (version 4.5.14), to communicate with this server in C# .NET 4.6.2.

My problem is: All the examples I found, e.g. http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization  are either about the server-side or about authentication against Facebook or Google.

I already implemented my own `CustomOAuth2Provider`, setting the access token URL, ConsumerSecret, etc.
But how do I tell the `JsonServiceClient`, to use this Provider, before executing the specific request?

Thank you, 
Daniel

Edit:

I read a lot of documentation and ServiceStack sourcecode, and I think my main problems are the following:

- I abuse the ServiceStack Client to communicate with a non-ServiceStack application, which I can not modify.
- Maybe the OAuth2 implementation of the third-party application is not 100% correct, as it expects authorization and token request in the same request.

But I got it working now and would like to show my solution here.
It still can be improved, e.g. it does not use the received refresh token right now.

```
public class ThirdPartyAuthenticator : IDisposable
{
    // TODO: Move to config
    public const string AccessTokenUrl = "";

    public const string ConsumerKey = "";
    public const string ConsumerSecret = "";

    public const string Username = "";
    public const string Password = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// Remember the last response, instance comprehensive so we do not need a new token for every request
    /// </summary>
    public static ServiceModel.ThirdPartyOAuth2Response LastOAuthResponse = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// This already authenticated client can be used for the data requests.
    /// </summary>
    public JsonServiceClient AuthenticatedServiceClient { get; set; }

    public ThirdPartyAuthenticator()
    {
        if (LastOAuthResponse == null || (LastOAuthResponse.ExpiryDateTime < DateTime.Now)) // TODO: Use Refresh token?
        {
            // Get token first
            JsonServiceClient authClient = new JsonServiceClient(AccessTokenUrl);
            authClient.UserName = ConsumerKey;
            authClient.Password = ConsumerSecret;
            authClient.AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true;

            var request = new ServiceModel.ThirdPartyOAuth2Request();
            request.Username = Username;
            request.Password = Password;

            // Use the Get URI, because server expects username + password as query parameter
            LastOAuthResponse = authClient.Post<ServiceModel.ThirdPartyOAuth2Response>(request.ToGetUrl(), request);
        }

        // If no exception was thrown, we have a valid token here.
        AuthenticatedServiceClient = new JsonServiceClient(AccessTokenUrl);
        AuthenticatedServiceClient.BearerToken = LastOAuthResponse.AccessToken;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        AuthenticatedServiceClient?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
using (var foo = new ThirdPartyAuthenticator())
{
    var response = foo.AuthenticatedServiceClient.Get(new ServiceModel.GetMyData() { SomeId = 10 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OAuth providers require a browser to redirect to the OAuth provider site where Users are able to accept authentication with the App and any permissions it requires. Once the user accepts they're redirected back to your ServiceStack App where it will create an Authenticated User Session. The session id from the Authenticated User Session is what's configured on the ServiceStack client to establish authenticated requests.

Here are some Example Apps which use OAuth to Authenticate using a browser then capture the browser redirect to extract the session cookies and configure it on the C# Service Client where they're then able to make Authenticated requests:

- https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacksAuth
- https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AndroidJavaChat

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't get it. I don't have a ServiceStack host right now - just a third party server application.
The client should just send an OAuth2 request to this server, to get an access token, before sending the data request itself.

I got it working now by writing a wrapper class for the client, which calls the Authentication request before the request itself.
Similar to the `ServiceStackAuthenticator` class in the TechStacks example.

Comment: @DanielP. The `ServiceStackAuthenticator` class wraps the [Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth#xamarinauth) which takes care of loading the Web UI, capturing user consent, redirecting back to the oauth redirect url than calling the ServiceStackAuthenticator.Completed callback so the Service Client can extract the authenticated session cookies on the browser and populate them on the Service Client.

Comment: @DanielP. If you manage to retrieve an OAuth2 token you can use it to Authenticate by setting it on `Authenticate.AccessToken` property as seen with the [Google OAuth2 example](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AndroidJavaChat#login-with-google-signin-button). This also needs to be implemented in your Custom AuthProvider, please read the [Release Notes of this feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.8#authentication-via-oauth-accesstokens) for details.

Comment: I added my current solution to the question. this way it works fine for me. Thank you for your support.